# OpenCV 2.4.6 linker error LNK2001

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, linker-errors, surf, sift

I am trying to run the `opencv surf` implementation [here](http://achuwilson.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/object-detection-using-surf-in-opencv-part-1/) in VS 2013.

I've already arranged the libraries in `Linker->Input` for example `opencv_core246.lib for release` and `opencv_core246d.lib for debug`.

But when I try to run the program, I getting the following error:

> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   cv::SIFT::SIFT(int,int,double,double,double)"
>   (??0SIFT@cv@@QAE@HHNNN@Z) C:...\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\surftest\surftest\main.obj  surftest

I already googled this error but found nothing useful.
Is there anyone knowing the reason for this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you linked against "opencv_features2d220d.lib"

Comment: Be aware, SIFT is in the nonfree module. You may need to link the nonfree library as well as features2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link it with

```
opencv_features2d246d.lib
opencv_nonfree246d.lib
```

for debug and for release

```
opencv_features2d246.lib
opencv_nonfree246.lib
```